# CakePHP url rewring forword request to another controller without changing request url

Tags: php, cakephp, url-rewriting, cakephp-1.3

i wont my request url   abc.com/xyz or abc.com/mobile   or abc.com/smartphone

i want to get response  **myController** and action **helloworld**

mean if my request url is not an controller just get response from myController and action helloworld
but not changing browser URl (not redirect )

Answer (score 1):

You need to define custom routes to map any URL to any controller and any action.

See the cookbook:
http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/development/routing.html

If that doesn't do what you need, you could use URL rewriting but that would be specific to your webserver.

Answer (score -1):

Solve this problem in `rotes.php` by adding

```
$routes->connect('/home/xxx/test', ['controller' => 'home', 'action' =>'index' ]);
```